# sum in blade how to do it for the subtotal of two tables?

Tags: laravel

i found out a way by someone asking a question, of a way of producing subtotals, i now just wanted to sum values between two tables , in the code from the person i tested and it works perfectly, i just wanted to aggregate more one table to any of the querys , it's summing on the blade.

```
//resumed controller
public function index() {
        $emphayas = DB::select('select * from emphayas');
        $treasuries = DB::select('select * from treasuries');
  return view('database',['emphayas'=>$emphayas, 
        'treasuries'=>$treasuries,
     ]);}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
//resumed blade
 <table class=" ">
         <tr>
            <th class="py-3 bg-cyan-400">Total</th>
            <td class="py-3 bg-cyan-400">available_for_use_month</td>
         </tr>

         @foreach ($emphayas as $emphaya)
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ $emphaya->available_for_use_month}}</td>
         </tr>
         @endforeach
         <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>{{ \App\Models\Emphaya::sum('available_for_use_month') }}
         </tr>
      </table>
<table class=" ">
         <tr>
            <th class="py-3 bg-cyan-400">Total</th>
            <td class="py-3 bg-cyan-400">available_for_use_month</td>
         </tr>
@foreach ($treasuries as $treasury)
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ $treasury->available_for_use_month}}</td>
</tr>
  @endforeach
         <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>{{ \App\Models\Treasury::sum('available_for_use_month') }}
</tr>
      </table>
```

in this case what i want to do is connect the total of treasury to emphyas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>{{ \App\Models\Emphaya::sum('available_for_use_month') + \App\Models\Treasury::sum('available_for_use_month') }}
  </tr>
```

Comment: @optimus899 mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem so other people can check as well, thank you!

Comment: i'm checking right now if it does i will mate rest assured i will put a big thumsup

Comment: It worked pretty well, i admire your skills, thank you very much for this @Apollo